# Xamarin Forms: Command and Event_Handler are not able to animate the rotation of an image

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, command, click

I´m using a ListView with an Image. I want to rotate the Image, but if i use a Command AND an Tapped-Event_Handler it does not rotate. Without the Command it rotates as expected.
Is there an easy way to animate Controls in View and not in Viewmodel?

Edit:

XAML:

```
<Image
    HeightRequest="40"
    WidthRequest="40"
    Aspect="Fill"
    Source="@drawable/arrowdown.png"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding BindingContext.PendingCommand, Source={x:Reference page}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

EventHandler:

```
bool trigger = true;
    public CreditPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = sender as Image;
        if (trigger)
        {
            image.RotateTo(180, 500);
            trigger = false;
        }
        else
        {
            image.RotateTo(0, 500);
            trigger = true;
        }
    }
```

Command:

```
private void OnPendingCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        Entry pendingEntry = obj as Entry;
        int index = Entries.IndexOf(pendingEntry);
        pendingEntry.IsPending = !pendingEntry.IsPending;
        Entries[index] = pendingEntry;
    }
```

Comment: When you get a chance, please edit the question and copy/paste your code for the ListView, Image, Tapped Event Handler and Command. We can't help fix your code unless we can review it.

Comment: I just tested and I found command and Tapped event works well at the same time under TapGestureRecognizer. Can you add you code of model and listView or any other details that can reproduce this problem?